# SQL oracle how to combine two conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

how can I combine these two conditions to one?

```
select ename, hiredate, next_day(last_day(hiredate)-7,5)
from emp
where to_number(to_char(hiredate, 'DD)) < 15 ORDER BY hiredate ASC;
```

and

```
select ename, hiredate, last_day(next_day(last_day(hiredate), 5))
from emp 
where to_number(to_char(hiredate, 'DD)) > 15 ORDER BY hiredate ASC;
```

I had an idea to store both of these to variables and then concatenate them.
However I'm currently new to sql oracle and I'm just not sure how to do it.
Maybe I can do something like? I hope you get the idea what i'm trying to accomplish.

```
Define variable1 = next_day(last_day(hiredate)-7,5)
where to_number(to_char(hiredate, 'DD)) < 15
```

Comment: Add some some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (i.e. not images.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression to determine which date to render based on the hire date.

```
select
    ename,
    hiredate,
    case when to_number(to_char(hiredate, 'DD')) < 15
         then next_day(last_day(hiredate)-7,5)
         when to_number(to_char(hiredate, 'DD')) > 15
         then last_day(next_day(last_day(hiredate), 5)) end AS date
from emp
order by hiredate ASC;
```

Note that it is not clear why you do not cover the following possibility:

```
to_number(to_char(hiredate, 'DD')) = 15
```

Perhaps you should bucket it with one of the other two conditions.

Comment: Big thank you to you. It's really easy to understand and use case expression now. However I get error message in 7th line. For some reason it does not change table name to 'date'

Comment: @CaL17 I use `date` as an _alias_ to the `CASE` expression.  In your result set, the `CASE` column should be labelled `date`; the table name has nothing to do with it.